# Django custom permissions not being recognized?

Tags: python, django, forms, web, permissions

I have custom permissions in my meta:

```
class Meta(): #extra bit of info
    model = User
    permissions = (
        ("has_uploaded", ("Has uploaded")),
        ("is_authenticated", ("Is authenticated")),
    )
    fields = ('email','emailConfirm','password1','biography','research_place','studies')
```

however when I try to do

```
is_auth_perm = Permission.objects.get(codename='is_authenticated')
request.user.user_permissions.add("is_auth_perm")
```

in my views I get the error that the permission does not exist, even after i do migrations and syncdb. am i doing something wrong?

Comment: You're using is_auth_perm as a string, is this a typo here or in your code `.add("is_auth_perm")`?

Comment: @danielcorreia thanks for noticing that, but that is not the entire error because the error is specifically on the line with is_auth_perm = etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add the permission to your model after first initializing the database? If so, the new permissions are not added to the database automatically even if you migrate.

To add the new permissions, you could use the `update_permissions` `manage.py` command from the `django-extensions` package.

Comment: Hi, yes, that must be my mistake. I installed django-extensions, added to settings.py installed apps and ran "python manage.py update_permissions" in the console--it ran the command but did not output anything. However I still get "Permission matching query does not exist." error?

Comment: After looking at your question again today, I noticed, that you have the ’model’ and ’field’ attributes in your meta class... This is usually not the case for model meta classes, but for form meta classes. did you, by any chance put your custom permissions in one of your forms? If so, move them to your model and then use 'update_permissions’ to sync the permissions